# How to interact with other GameObjetcs using the input system of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to be able to interact with NPCs in a 2D platformer in Unity.
I would like to use the input system here.
I have also created a new action (Interaction) in the InputActions that listens to whether I press E or not.

Listening if E is pressed works, but only in the script I apply to the player.

```
void OnInteract(InputValue value)
    {
        if (myBoxCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Interactables")))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello Player");
        }
    }
```

However, I want to run a different script depending on which NPC/Gameobject the games interacts with. I would like to do this in order to be able to display specific dialogues or to exit the scene by pressing E.

Is there a way to somehow check in another script if the player is in the desired collider and presses e? Or a way to run the code from the Other GameObject in the script from the player.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all, you could add a tag / specific component to the interactable object which could help when identificating which object actually is.
I'd intead of using layers rather use a trigger system.
Ex:

```
OnTriggerEnter(collider col) {
  if (col.layer == 'interactables') currentTrigger = col.gameObject;
}
OnTriggerExitcollider col) {
  if (col.layer == 'interactables') currentTrigger = null;
}
```

Then, when you check an input get the trigger you're in (if there is) and operate with it, adjusting the response of the game to the object. you could even add a component to the object and execue a script when its interacted